# Ошибка при generate-signed-apk

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle

```
Lint found fatal errors while assembling a release target.

To proceed, either fix the issues identified by lint, or modify your build script as follows:
...
android {
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }
}
...
```

Если я последую советам, то все apk создаться.
Но что это за ошибка? Из-за чего? Какие могут быть последствия?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При сборке релизной версии приложения [androidLint](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/lint) ищет ошибки, и если находит, то фейлит сборку. Поэтому вам предложили два варианта - поправить все ошибки в коде, которые нашел [androidLint](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/lint), или выключить опцию, которая фейлит сборку при ошибках.

Comment: где посмотреть, на что он ругается?

Comment: Должен формироваться отчет в папку `app/build/reports/lint-results.html`

Comment: и правда там ошибка! да еще показаны что за ошибка и где! но тогда доп.вопрос для общего развития: а почему это вылезло при создании apk? почему раньше не показывало ошибки?